# spring boot runs data.sql twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

*aplication.properties*:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/webdev_simplified
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
#spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

Now if I run `mvn clean package` I can see the table is created and data.sql executed (tested in local postgres that data is there - i.e. `select * from cart_item` returns data). This was for packaging and after then, when run as `java -jar target/app.jar`, it again executes the `data.sql` (or I think it does, but I ended up with duplicate data (or rather inserted is better word since data is not duplicated, their keys are incremeneted, as in sql insert). So how to prevent the second execution of `data.sql`?

Full source code:
https://github.com/shepherd123456/springapp_with_postgres/

what is strange is that running the same application with mysql does not run execute the data.sql twice. That is, with mysql, it work correctly. So why it does not with postgres

Comment: f you run `package` it will run tests, which will read and use your configuration. Which will create the datbase. You shouldn't use `data.sql` in production use seomthing like Flyway or LIquibase for more elaborate support and solutions.

Comment: Why? I dont know these libraries, why cannot pure spring hibernate do the job in production? Why always need to use third party

Comment: Because **you** want to control your schema, you don't want to hand that over to your ORM framework. Which might decide to drop a column because of crappy mapping, it won't properly update if you modify fields (like length, type etc.) nor will it migrate your data. It is nice for toy projects not for real-life projects. Flyway is one way to properly manage and version your schema.

Comment: @M.Deinum also, what is strange is that running the same application with mysql does not run execute the `data.sql` twice. That is, with mysql, it work correctly. So why it does not with postgres?

Comment: I doubt that it doesn't run twice but that for some reason the records don't get inserted (due to a different schema being generated by hibernate).

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please elaborate? Does hibernate handles mysql schema differently then postrgres? Particularly, in both cases, we are just talking about insertion, not creation (that is done by hibernate if you specify ddl-auto to update or create). And insertion is the same for both mysql and postgres (`insert into <table>(<columns...>) values(<values>...)`, so why and how does hibernate do it differently?

Comment: MySQL is a different dialect, as you let Hibernate generate your schema it might use different types, constraints as each dtabase is different (hence the use for Flyway that way you know for certain what is being executed). Due to the difference is schema it might be that PostgreSQL inserts the data double and MySQL overrides (one has sequences the other not IIRC).

Comment: The reason I asked is they are very similar in developer aspect, that is sql language is same. Only postgres is older and more mature database so has more features, and I know about the generation of IDs where in mysql is simply `auto_increment` on primary key whereas postgres creates separate sequence object which increments. So could I consider this "id generation" as the reason postgres was executed twice whereas mysql once?

Comment: The `data.sql` is executed twice (I suggest you enable debug logging and check that). The result of the inserts is apparently different.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG`, how else should I see the debugged execution?

Comment: It isn't hibernate that executes the `data.sql` but Spring.